# python hadoop : mapreduce job is not working

Tags: python, hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs, sequencefile

my map reduce program is processing 20 videos so i have  uploaded 20 videos in hdfs, when i start executing the map reduce code on terminal its not proceeding. when i run this command `pydoop submit --upload-file-to-cache stage1.py stage1 path_directory stage1_output` its got stop.the log on terminal is as follows.

```
hduser@Barca-FC:/home/uday/Project/final project/algo2$ pydoop submit --upload-file-to-cache twodct.py twodct  path_directory twodct_output
16/05/30 18:19:20 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
16/05/30 18:19:21 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at /0.0.0.0:8032
16/05/30 18:19:22 WARN mapreduce.JobSubmitter: No job jar file set.  User classes may not be found. See Job or Job#setJar(String).
16/05/30 18:19:22 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 1
16/05/30 18:19:22 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: number of splits:1
16/05/30 18:19:22 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Submitting tokens for job: job_1464609268645_0002
16/05/30 18:19:23 INFO mapred.YARNRunner: Job jar is not present. Not adding any jar to the list of resources.
16/05/30 18:19:23 INFO impl.YarnClientImpl: Submitted application application_1464609268645_0002
16/05/30 18:19:23 INFO mapreduce.Job: The url to track the job: http://Barca-FC:8088/proxy/application_1464609268645_0002/
16/05/30 18:19:23 INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_1464609268645_0002
```

my hadoop configuration file are like this:

```
mapred-site.xml:
<configuration>
<property>
  <name>mapred.job.tracker</name>
  <value>localhost:54311</value>
  <description>The host and port that the MapReduce job tracker runs
  at.  If "local", then jobs are run in-process as a single map
  and reduce task.
  </description>
 </property>
<property>
<name>mapred.reduce.tasks</name>
<value>1</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>mapreduce.framework.name</name>
<value>yarn</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

hdfs-site.xml:

```
<configuration>
<property>
  <name>dfs.replication</name>
  <value>1</value>
  <description>Default block replication.
  The actual number of replications can be specified when the file is created.
  The default is used if replication is not specified in create time.
  </description>
 </property>
 <property>
   <name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name>
   <value>file:/usr/local/hadoop_store/hdfs/namenode</value>
 </property>
 <property>
   <name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name>
   <value>file:/usr/local/hadoop_store/hdfs/datanode</value>
 </property>
<property>
 <name>dfs.webhdfs.enabled</name>
 <value>true</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

core-site.xml:

```
<configuration>
<property>
  <name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name>
  <value>/app/hadoop/tmp</value>
  <description>A base for other temporary directories.</description>
 </property>

 <property>
  <name>fs.default.name</name>
  <value>hdfs://localhost:54310</value>
  <description>The name of the default file system.  A URI whose
  scheme and authority determine the FileSystem implementation.  The
  uri's scheme determines the config property (fs.SCHEME.impl) naming
  the FileSystem implementation class.  The uri's authority is used to
  determine the host, port, etc. for a filesystem.</description>
 </property>
<property>
<name>fs.defaultFS</name>
<value>hdfs://localhost:9000</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

can anyone please tell me why my mapreduce job is not proceeding?
Thanks in Advance!

Comment: dose the map reduce code use any native libraries w.r.t video's, if so the native libraries need to be available on the nodes.